# Get only year from DateTimePicker

Tags: winforms, datetimepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` called `dtProcurationDate` it show the date as custom format `yyyy/M/d` .. now i'm trying to get only the year from it with code

```
string year = dtProcurationDate.Value.Year.ToString();
```

also tried

```
this.dtProcurationDate.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
string year = dtProcurationDate.Value.Year.ToString();
```

but it gives me a null value ..

Comment: That simply can't happen.  The Value property of a datetime picker is of type DateTime, that is a struct so it can't be null. The year prpperty is an int, another struct. Plus if it was possible to have a null value you would get a null reference exception. Something else is going on. Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: yes .. it gives me a null value in the debugging mode

Comment: Which value is null?

Comment: `year` value ... i'm sure that i did something stupid .. still trying

Comment: [Looking at the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b) it has a contract declaration that says the result will not be null, so something else must be going on. It would help if you posted a complete example because the fragment doesn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
//syntax is datetimepicker.Value.Year

int year = dtProcurationDate.Value.Year; //your case
```